# Contact Form iframe redirection

Tags: php, forms, iframe

I have a contact form at http://www.brisbanediveacademy.com.au made using php. I'm trying to get it to redirect to a new page inside the iframe after the form has being submitted. I'm having trouble gettting it to redirect anywhere at the moment.

Here is my PHP

```
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'enquiries@brisbanediveacademy.com.au';
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$contact = $_POST['number'];
$inquiry = $_POST['inquiry'];  
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 
if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
     $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}
if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "Website contact Form Enquiry: $inquiry";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Contact Number:  $contact \n Message: \n $message"; 
    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers = "Reply-To: $email_address";"\r\n";
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
} 
?>
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: where is the code for redirection?

Comment: i have checked with your site. the problem is you have empty spaces or print something before set the header for redirection. remove those space or lines and set the header before printing anything on the page.

Comment: Are you able to give an example sorry, not 100% sure what you mean. I had the redirects in there but have recently taken them out.

Comment: in mail.php, check line no 37, you have printed something or there is an HTML space. remove that will solve the problem. or attach the mail.php here for investigation.

Answer (score 0):

I can see this error report

`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/brisbane/public_html/contact/mail.php:9) in /home/brisbane/public_html/contact/mail.php on line 37`

This means that, the code before `header('Location:..')` have some kind of output oriented code like an echo. Find your setting for error logs, check for echo. Preferably you can check on line 37 of mail.php. Mostly this will be because your php conf has display_errors true and error_reporting is set to lowest level. So even if a NOTICE is generated, it will set the header before you do.  Add these lines at just after `<?php`

```
    error_reporting(E_ERROR);
    ini_set('display_errors','false');
```

even the second line only will do.

EDIT:
 as you asked, the redirection is possible with this line of code.

`header("Location: url-to-redirect");`

if you don't have this line of code in your file, please verify that you are doing the right thing for your requirement.

Hopes this will help some way.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to redirect to a new page inside that iframe?

Answer (score 0):

In the code you should have a redirection code something like following,

```
<?php
/* Redirect browser */
header("Location: http://www.brisbanediveacademy.com.au/");
?>
```